# remove column that shows status of checkbox from datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms

[image]

I added a checkbox to a datagrid but now it shows this other column. How to I get rid of it?

Comment: Just a guess, but I think that's the row header. So set `RowHeadersVisible` to false.

Comment: it's odd, I have row headers set to false but it still shows up. When I enable row headers it inserts another column

Comment: @Plutonix yes it is

Comment: Is it **(*`DataGridView`*)** perhaps bound to a dataset or table?

Comment: when the program first runs it isn't bound @zaggler

Comment: I think there is something missing.  Is this a standard DGV with standard .NET columns?  Does the code add the columns or are they autogenerated?  I've never seen the DGV display a column in the rowheader area.

Comment: The problem exists as soon as the program is run, at that time it is unbound and no columns are added except for that checkbox which is added through the datagridviews properties. I add additional columns later on. @Plutonix

Comment: It doesnt even look like a standard check column - more like something rendered in a paint event

Comment: @Plutonix I can't figure out where it came from, it's literally just a datagridview with a checkbox column added, there's nothing special about it. It has to be some stupid property I have set to true somewhere.

Comment: @AlexF11 In your original question you say the first checkbox column you don't want was added after you added another checkbox column.  But then in the comments you say it appears before you create any other columns.  Clearing that up would help.  If you could post the code of how you initialize the grid and then also of how you create your other columns that would be helpful.  I'm not aware of any native setting that would let you turn the checkboxes on in the row header.  A bigger screen shot might help as well or screen shots before and after your other columns are created would also help.